# When Truth Meets Fiction

Tags: fiction, publishing, education, memoir, categories

Is there such a category in books as a fictional memoir (tales about one's own life with exaggerated elements included for entertainment)?

Comment: Most memoirs include substantial amounts of exaggeration if not fictional elements. Look at Clive James' 'An Unreliable Memoir', for example.

Comment: Then I'm curious as to how do you box the case of James Frey's A MILLION LITTLE PIECES, which was originally sold as a memoir, before being sold as semi-fictional?

Comment: Welcome, La-V. This is a good question, but one that has been asked and answered here before: [What Genre Category for a Semi-Fictional Memoir?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/32737/what-genre-category-for-a-semi-fictional-memoir).  You might also find this relevant: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/26159/my-autobiography-is-exciting-but-im-an-unknown-should-i-make-it-a-novel-inste/36913#36913